# How to call a method with different Generic type

Tags: java, generics, methods

I've got to implement these two methods using recursivity:
- The first one is to return a value at a Node in the PositionList
- The second one to convert a crypted `List<Integer>` into a (`<Character>`) List

in the decrypt method I´m trying to call the getPositon method but getting the Error 
"The method `getPosition(PositionList<E>, Position<E>, int)` in the type Recursion is not applicable for the arguments `(PositionList<Character>, Position<Integer>, int)`"

How can I call .decrypt giving it a `PositonList<Character>` and a `Position<Integer>`?

```
public static <E> Position<E> getPosition(PositionList<E> l, Position<E> pos, int n) {

     if(n < 0) {
         pos = l.prev(pos);
         return getPosition(l, pos, n+1);
     }
     if(n > 0) {
         pos = l.next(pos);
         return getPosition(l, pos, n-1);
     }
     else {
         return pos;
     }
  }

  public static PositionList<Character> decrypt(PositionList<Character> alphabet, PositionList<Integer> encodedText) {

      PositionList<Character> newList;
      Position<Integer> pos; 


      if(counter <= alphabet.size()) {
          if(counter == 0) {
              pos = encodedText.first();
              value = pos.element();
          }
          if(counter > 0) {
              pos = encodedText.next(pos);
              value = pos.element();
          }
          newList.addLast(getPosition(alphabet, pos, value));
          counter++;
          return decrypt(alphabet, encodedText);
      }

      else {
          counter = 0;
          return newList;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple generic types to methods like so:

```
public static <E, F> Position<F> getPosition(PositionList<E> l, Position<F> pos, int n) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In this case I`ll get the same error for the next and prev methods inside .getPosition:

The method next(Position<E>) in the type PositionList<E> is not applicable for the arguments (Position<F>)

Comment: Maybe you should use a `Position<Character>` instead of a `Position<Integer>`? Then you don't need two generic parameters.

Comment: I have to use Position<Integer> because the decrypt method is getting a PositionList<Integer>